# Django: import error with django-admin.py

Tags: django

Currently I have created two symbolic links for Django in `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/`. A `ls -l` shows the following

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 hobbes3  staff    66B Feb 23 04:16 django -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 hobbes3  staff    85B Feb 23 01:01 django-admin.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
drwxr-xr-x  15 hobbes3  staff   510B Feb 24 16:04 mysite/
```

where `mysite/` is my only Django project (built from the official Polls tutorial).

When I type `python django-admin.py`, everything works fine

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites$ python django-admin.py
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=all output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:
  cleanup
  compilemessages
  createcachetable
  dbshell
  diffsettings
  dumpdata
  flush
  inspectdb
  loaddata
  makemessages
  reset
  runfcgi
  runserver
  shell
  sql
  sqlall
  sqlclear
  sqlcustom
  sqlflush
  sqlindexes
  sqlinitialdata
  sqlreset
  sqlsequencereset
  startapp
  startproject
  syncdb
  test
  testserver
  validate
```

But when I try to use the `inspectdb` command, I get an import error

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites$ python django-admin.py inspectdb doors-eer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I noticed that I can start projects just fine with `python django-admin.py startproject asd`.

I'm running Python 2.7.2 and Django 1.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django-admin.py is looking for your settings.py file which should be in /Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite.

If you cd into ~/Sites/mysite then run django-admin.py inspectdb doors-eer it should work.

This assumes that you have the DATABASE variable setup in settings.py.

Also, after you have created the project the more conventional way to use Django is by calling manage.py inspectdb once you have created your project. By calling django-admin.py the environment variables don't get setup correctly and Django won't find your settings.py file.

Comment: Ok so I `cd mysite` then run `python ../django-admin.py inspectdb door-eer` and it still gives me the same error. I opened `settings.py` and I verified that my `DATABASE` variable is set up correctly...

Comment: After changing into the directory /mysite run python manage.py inspectdb with no arguments.

Comment: Oh I just realized you said to use `manage.py` inside `mysite` instead of `django-admin.py`. Thanks that worked for me for now. Now I just need to create a new project temporary to read the `doors-eer` database, then run `inspectdb`.

Comment: But in the future, how can I fix the `django-admin.py` commands?

Comment: When you create a project using python django-admin.py startproject myproject Django will create a directory called 'myproject' and will prepopulate that directory with all the files you need to get started with Django:

settings.py
manage.py
urls.py